# Without (much) calculation show that if $|z| = 1$ then $ \Im\left(\frac{z}{(z+1)^2}\right)=0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

The title pretty much says it.

> Given that $z$ lies on the unit circle i.e. $|z| = 1$
>   show that
>
> $$ \Im\left(\frac{z}{(z+1)^2}\right)=0 $$
>
> with little to no calculation involved( a geometric/visual solution beeing optimal).

Here is my (best guess at a) solution:

$ \Im\left(\dfrac{z}{(z+1)^2}\right)=0 $ implies that the angle between $z$ and $(z+1)^2$ is a multiple of pi. Hence to show that the result is true we must show/argue that $z$ and $z+1$ lie on the same line.

This is what I have so far, but I don't see how to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thinking about my solution I notice that "lie on the same line" is pretty ambiguous... What I meant was lie on the line y = z in the complex plane.

Comment: $$\Im\left(\frac{z}{z^2+2z+1}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{1}{z+2+1/z}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{1}{2(z+1)}\right)=0$$
that is $\Im(z+1)=0$ or real line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try a more geometric perspective. Look at the following sketch

[image]

Here the point $\rm A$ represents $z$ and the point $\rm C$ represents $z+1$. Our goal is to show that $\angle \rm ABD=2\angle \rm ABC=2\angle \rm CBD$, which then proves that $z$ and $\left(z+1\right)^{2}$ both have the same angle and so $\frac{z}{\left(z+1\right)^{2}}$ is real. But that's easy because the triangle $\Delta\rm ABC$ is isosceles (which is true given ${\rm AB}=\left|z\right|=1$) so $\angle \rm ABC=\angle \rm ACB$, and also $\angle \rm ACB=\angle \rm CBD$ because $\rm AC$ is parallel to $\rm BD$.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the approach I was looking for. So if I understand your argument correctly we are trying to show that $(z+1)$'s angle is half as large as $z$'s angle. Then since $(z+1)^2$ will have twice $(z+1)$'s angle it will have $z$'s angle.

Comment: @wittbluenote Exactly. You've got it right!

Answer (score 2):

If $z\ne -1$ then $\left(\frac {z}{(z+1)^2}\right)^{-1}=2+z+\frac {1}{z}.$

If $z=a+ib$ with $a,b\in \Bbb R$ then $$|z|=1\implies 1=|z|^2=a^2+b^2\implies 1=(a+ib)(a-ib)\implies \frac {1}{z}=a-ib\implies$$ $$\implies 2+z+\frac {1}{z}=2+2a\in \Bbb R.$$

The fact that $\frac {1}{z}=\overline z=Re(z)-iIm(z)$ when $|z|=1$ is something to calculate ONCE. It's used all the time.

Comment: what is $\left(\frac {z}{(z+1)^2}\right)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Rationalize the denominator and recall that $z\overline z+|z|^2$:
$$\frac z{(z+1)^2}=\frac z{(z+1)^2}\frac{(\overline z+1)^2}{(\overline z+1)^2}=\frac{|z|^2(\overline z+2)+z}{|z+1|^4}=\frac{z+\overline z+2}{|z+1|^4},$$which is clearly real. (Don't know whether that counts as "not much calculation" - it's  better than the mess you'd get starting with $z=x+iy$...)

**Now** he tells us he needs a "geometric/visual" solution. Fine, but you have to draw the picture yourself:

Draw a little picture with the points $A=0$, $B=z$, $C=z+1$ and $D=1$ labelled. Now $ABC$ is an isoceles triangle, hence $\angle BCA=\angle BAC$. Since the line $y=c$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, $\angle CAD = \angle ACB$. So $\angle BAD=2\angle CAD$. This says that $\arg z=2\arg(z+1)=\arg(z+1)^2$, hence $z/(z+1)^2$ is real.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but helpful as it is I doubt this was the requested "geometric/visual" solution requested.

Comment: Or just write it as $\frac1{z+2+\overline z}$.

Comment: @wittbluenote If it asked for a "geometric/visual" solution you should have said so...

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich I thought " with as little calculation as possible" indicated that a geometric/visual solution would be optimal. I am sorry if I caused confusion. I have added this information in my question post.

Comment: @wittbluenote geometirc/visual solution added...

Comment: Thank you! Again sorry if I caused confusion. I copied the question and the wording of the question from a book I did not invent it...

Comment: @wittbluenote So why the downvote?

Comment: @ David C. Ulrich I never down voted your question. In fact I up voted it.

Answer (score 0):

Another "easy-ish" way is to make the parametrization $z = e^{i\theta}$, then

$$ \frac{z}{(1+z)^2} = \frac{1}{e^{i\theta} + 2 + e^{-i\theta}} = \frac{1}{2 + \cos \theta} $$

which is a real number.

To me that's very little calculation, but I can see your book wants a geometric solution without explicitly saying it.